# Does Converting a byte array to object increases the size..?

Tags: java, arrays

my code is as follows..

```
private Object populateObj(InputStream inputStream) {
        int i=0;
        Object resObject = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int next = inputStream.read();
            while (next > -1) {
                i++;
                bos.write(next);
                next = inputStream.read();
            }
            bos.flush();
            byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("Size of byte array 1: "+result.length);
            System.out.println("Result is []");
            for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++){
                System.out.println(result[j]);
            }
            resObject = result;
            byte[]  result2=toByteArray(resObject);
            System.out.println("Size of byte array 2 : "+result2.length);
            System.out.println("Result2 is []");
            for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++){
                System.out.println(result2[j]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("size of inputStream in bytes : "+i);
        return resObject;
    }
```

code for converting object to byte array is:-

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

when i compare the length of the both the byte arrays its different.some extra byte are added but at which point of conversion..?(while assigning the byte array to object or when) 
Size of input Stream comes same as first byte array.

I want to convert the Inputstream of http request into a resObject which can be then given to outputstream.Using ObjectInputStream.readObject() gives StreamCorruptedException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're serializing a byte array using Java object serialization. This has an overhead over the raw byte array, since the serialized stream contains a serialization header, the name of the class of the object being serialized, and probably some additional bytes to be able to know where the object starts and ends in the stream.

Remember that, when deserializing, the receiver knows nothing about the contents of the ObjectInputStream. So it must be able to know that what has been serialized is a single byte array (and not a String, an Integer or any other serializable object). So this information has to be stored somehow in the stream, and thus needs some additional bytes.

Comment: so how should i retrieve the original input Stream.If i directly retrieve it from object by converting it into byte Array,some garbage are added at the start of file..

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using object serialization in the first place if all you want to do is write one byte array to a file. But you do it using `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`.

Comment: I want to convert the Inputstream of http request into Object.Using ObjectInputStream.readObject() gives StreamCorruptedException.Is there any way to remove the extra bytes.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you want to achieve. Edit your question, and post the actual code, and the complete stack trace of the exception. You keep talking about converting an InputStream to Object. But InputStream is already an Object. And byte[] is also an Object.

Comment: Can you plz tell me where the addition bytes are added.During `resObject = result` or while reconstructiong the byte array by calling `toByteArray(Object)`

Comment: Assigning an object to a variable will never change the value of an object. Of course it's the toByteArray() method. That's where you're serializing your array using an ObjectOutputStream. You seem to really not understand what you're doing. Why are you transforming a byte array into another byte array using serialization. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
    byte[] array = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    System.out.println(array.length);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(array);
    oos.close();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();

    System.out.println(((byte[]) obj).length);
```